# Which jBoss and EJB3 features should I use for Web Crawler

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, web-crawler, jboss5.x

Happy New Year everybody,now I am trying to develop my own bot([web crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)) that will walk around through Internet, for search engine. I am thinking to use jboss scheduler-service to schedule bot and something like this to get content:

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.google.kz");
  InputStream in = u.openStream();
```

**I want to ask which EJB3 or jBoss features should I use to develop effectively(in right way) my bot?**
I am new to EJB3 and jBoss.

If you have better ideas, you could right here.I am developing search engine to practice my Java skills and in academical issues, I am not going to compete with Google :)

- jboss-5.1.0.GA
- XP
- EJB3
- Eclipse helios

P.S. I didn't decide yet how I will parse html, I am thinking about something like this [Parse HTML](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/ParseHTML.htm). What can you recommend?

Comment: @Bohzo's right, these are not relevant technologies for what you're trying to do. They won't obstruct you, but they're not much use to you, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need EJB or JBoss at all. In fact I can hardly think of a use of them for a web-crawler. Only perhaps if you are using JPA to store the results from the crawl, then you can make use of container-managed transactions, and the automatic injection of the JPA entity manager. Apart from that - no.

Comment: Thanks, I am new for EJB and jBoss, I though that there are some features that can be helpful in this task. But I will wait for other answers.